# How to make sure the computer runs on NZST programmatically

Tags: c#, windows

How can I sync the system time to NZST by w32tm?

And how can I make sure it wont be changed back by auto-sync PROGRAMMATICALLY?

Thx in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying to stop the user choosing their time zone?

If you have a legitimate reason for this (i.e. you're a sysadmin), then define appropriate Group Policy. Otherwise, the user is capable of choosing their own time zone just fine.